# How to get current date and time

Tags: javascript, angular

Need get current date and time with my timezone that is UTC-3, in this format 2021-02-05 12:45:00. How is this possible in Angular?

my current ts using

```
fechaHoy = new Date();
```

Comment: use moment https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Comment: Do not use moment, use dayjs or date-fns. Moment is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend the dateFormat module (moment.js is deprecated).
Firstly, install the module as follows - always back up your work with Git beforea adding unknown dependencies of course

`npm i dateformat`

Then call:

```
//Import Module
let dateFormat = require('dateformat');

//Instantiate New Date & then call func and parse date.
let date = new Date();
var currDate = dateFormat(date, "yyyy, dddd, mmmm dS, h:MM:ss TT");
```

You could then use currDate to update a field etc.

Comment: in this way how do I change the timezone?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
 function formatMyDate(date) {
     function minTwoDigits(n) {
        return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
    }
 
   return date.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+minTwoDigits(date.getUTCMonth())+"-"+minTwoDigits(date.getUTCDate())+" "+
   minTwoDigits(date.getUTCHours())+":"+ minTwoDigits(date.getUTCMinutes())+":"+  minTwoDigits(date.getUTCSeconds())
 }
```

call this function with date object

```
formatMyDate(new Date())
//output "2021-01-05 15:03:19"
```